# 404 Error when running TicTacToe sample (Android) against sample Google App Engine project (Java)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

I set up the Android App and Google App Engine backend as seen in these two projects:

1. [Android Connected App Engine Project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android)
2. [Java App Engine Backend Project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java)

When I click a TicTacToe-field button, which triggers a request I get an 404 error: "Not found"

```
04-09 23:11:51.115: W/TicTacToe(26247): GetComputerMoveTask: 404 Not Found
04-09 23:11:51.115: W/TicTacToe(26247): Not Found
```

That is exactly the what https://***myappname***.appspot.com/_ah/api/ in the browser  shows "Not Found".

Here is what I did:

1. Created an api project on [App Engine Console](https://appengine.google.com/)
2. There created an Android Client Id with com.google.devrel.samples.ttt as package an my debug keys SHA1-fingerprint
3. There created a Web Client ID
4. Integrated the Android Project in eclipse. Updated DEFAULT_ROOT_URL in Tictactoe.java to "https://***myappname***.appspot.com/_ah/api/"
5. There updated the value of AUDIENCE in ClientCredentials.java by replacing the string "your_web_client_id" with the generated ***web-client-id*** from step 3
6. Integrated the Java backend project in eclipse.There updated the value of application in appengine-web.xml to ***myappname***
7. Updated the values in /spi/Ids.java to reflect the ***web-client-id*** and ***android-client-id*** from step 2 and 3
8. Updated the value of google.devrel.samples.ttt.CLIENT_ID in war/js/render with ***web-client-id***
9. Deployed the backend to google. Worked great - it opend the https://***myappname***.appspot.com/ page showing the correct page after deploying (servlet)
10. Deployed the android app and tried to make a move in TicTacToe. The app crashes.

I think its very suspicious my DEFAULT_ROOT_URL is set to "https://***myappname***.appspot.com/_ah/api/" in my Android app whereas this pages show just "Not found" in the browser.

Whats going wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Want to add that the log as well does not show any acess in the Console.

Comment: Addiotianally https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://myapname.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/ shows no entries for Services, All Versions and Request History ?!! I also checked in the API console that latest version is set as default. 
I compiled the backend with JRE 1.7. The google-play-services project was taken from the android-sdk-folder. I again checked the URLs for the Android Client ID, and Web Client ID nd the Application ID were correctly set up and inserted.

Comment: + I use a real device only (no emulator) that uses the permitted accounts (set in console) only. The web frontend still is available. The console shows sucess messages after deployment. The exception in the stack trace is: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found

Comment: ... and also checked again the fingerprint used for the Android Cleint ID and device deployment.

Comment: I got solved this issue by setting up the project again. I cannot really explain why it works now.. Thank you all anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Try to test your API at https://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api/tictactoe/v1/ and see if that doesn't do what you want.

Research from this link:https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/tictactoe/Tictactoe.java

Lines 60-74

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java/blob/master/src/com/google/devrel/samples/ttt/spi/BoardV1.java

Lines 29-31

I suspect you have the API URL wrong, and diving in the code its apparent that the above URL is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I even imported that project. Just as seen there I filled <myappname> in TicTacToe.java in line 60. Beside changiging the values as shown in the description its the same project. When I call https://myappname.appspot.com/_ah/api/tictactoe/v1/ it shows 404 - "Not Found" as well.

Comment: Do you have your code up in a repo somewhere we could look at? It can of course have any private or sensitive info removed if you are concerned about that - just need the logic.

Comment: Could you also look into the logs for the App Engine Project? I believe you are only looking at the logs from the Android system. Go to the [Google Developers Console](console.developers.google.com), choose your project, and navigate to Monitoring->Logs. Look for any errors there, perhaps something will jump out to you (or us).

Answer (score 0):

No idea where are you getting the instructions for step 4 (in your list), but looking at [Setup Instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android#setup-instructions) in the for the Android project, step 2, what you should do is:

> Update the value of `DEFAULT_ROOT_URL` in `src/com/appspot/api/services/tictactoe/Tictactoe.java` to point to the location where you are hosting a Tic Tac Toe backend (based off of the Java backend example).

And the location in your case is crearly "https://**myappname**.appspot.com/".

Comment: Yes in sample code on the internet I often found https://myappname.appspot.com/_ah/api/. But as well I tried https://myappname.appspot.com/. This comes to a 404 error as well, but in this case I see the html code of my servlet samples page in the stack trace. It seems to be that there is no API available on those UIRLs.